# svn checkout error E120107 while setting up SSL Tunnel and unable to connect to a repository

Tags: svn

I am trying to checkout SWEET source code via the command

```
svn co --username ****** --password ******** https://v-lagerlunda.ita.mdh.se:8443/svn/wcet/sweet/trunk/ SWEET
```

which is returning the error

> svn: E120107: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'https://v-lagerlunda.ita.mdh.se:8443/svn/wcet/sweet/trunk' and svn:
>   E120107: Error running context: The proxy server returned an error
>   while setting up the SSL tunnel.

I have already edited /etc/subversion/servers and ~/.subversion/servers and added my proxy. svn is running fine when I give the command

```
svn co https://svn.eionet.europa.eu/repositories/Zope/trunk/RDFCalendar temp
```

This shows that my proxy is set correctly and svn works fine for https links. I think the problem might be related to the username and password given to me to grant read  access to the SWEET source code.

Comment: These are completely different URLs pointing to different servers. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Verify [proxy settings of your Subversion client](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers). Proxy settings are specified in `servers` file:

   - `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers` on Windows,
   - `/etc/subversion/servers` on Linux.
2. Upgrade your Subversion client. This could be a bug in serf library, see [Serf Issue 120: "Error with ssl tunnel over proxy with KeepAlive off and Basic authentication"](https://code.google.com/p/serf/issues/detail?id=120).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already added proxy to svn . svn works fine for other cases but gives me error in this case only. I am using svn version 1.8.8 and serf 1.3.3.

Comment: @saurav you can't update serf without updating Subversion (or building the client yourself).

Comment: This issue was with serf 1.2.1 and my serf version is 1.3.3.